# htaccess - Redirect All but Sub-Directory (Ember js)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, ember.js

I am running my main website with Ember and because of that have my htaccess file set up to redirect all requests to my index page for routing.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

However, I have since added a sub-directory called `/horror` that is also running on Ember. Any request made to `domain.com/horror` I want to have redirect to `/horror/index.html` again, for proper routing.

Currently, when I access `domain.com/horror` the page runs. But if I try going directly to `domain.com/horror/1` I am redirected to my main domain's 404 page and not to the correct `/horror/` route. I need this `/horror` directory to function as a standalone site - accessing its own CSS, Js, and images without conflicting with the main domain's Ember router.

How can I configure my .htaccess file to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a separate rule for handling `/horror/`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/horror/index\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^horror(/.*)?$ horror/index.html [L,NC]    

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Comment: I should rephrase my question, I still need my requests to horror/.css, .js, .jpg ect... to work fine. Looks like testing this forces all of those requests still to go to index.

Comment: Closer. Now, when I go to /horror the initial load works. But if I go to /horror/1, for example, I still receive my main domain's 404 page.

Comment: You have absolutely made my day. Thank you, this works perfectly!